# Do mongoose query on Dropdown changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First of I want to say that I am new to JS and mongoose/MongoDB.

I made a page where I show some data I have stored in mongoDB and that is working fine. Now I made a dropdown menu with some options and I want to update one field based on the value I select in the dropdown menu.

Basically my question is: how do update one field in the mongoDB when the onchanged of the Dropdown menu is triggered?

Here is my Schema I want to update:

/src/models/itemmodel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose);
console.log('/src/models/itemmodel.js');

// Create a Schema for items
const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, default: '' },
    description: { type: String, default: '' },
    createdBy: { type: String, default: '' },
    masco: { type: String, default: '' },
    projectName: { type: String, default: '' },
    projectNumber: { type: Number, default: '' },
    createdDate: { type: String, default: '' },
    lastUpdate: { type: String, default: '' },
    status: { type: String, default: 'New' },
    responsible: { type: String, default: 'Not defined' },
    affectedSystem: { type: String, default: 'Not defined' },
    seqId: Number,
    itemId: { type: String, default: '' },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);
```

And this is how i have setup the Dropdownmenu:

```
<% var id = ''; %>
  <select name="" id="statusDropdown" class="dropbtn" onchange="getSelectedValue(this);">
      <% var states = [ 'New', 'Assigned', 'In progess']; %>
      <% var selectedId = items._id; %>
      <%  for ( var i = 0; i < states.length; i++ ) { %>
        <% var selected = ( id == i ) ? "selected" : ""; %>
        <option value='{"state": "<%=states[i]%>", "id": "<%=items._id%>"}' >  <%=states[i] %> </option>
        <% } %>
  </select>
```

I am calling the function getSelectedValue(this) here and i have this function in the same file in the . I am receiving the data i want, the _id and the onchanged value.

```
<script>
  var ItemModel = require("../src/models/itemmodel.js");
  
  function getSelectedValue(selectObject) {
      var statusOfItem = JSON.parse(selectObject.value);
      console.log(statusOfItem.state);
      console.log(statusOfItem.id);
    
    
      var e = document.getElementById("statusDropdown");
      var newStatus = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
      console.log(statusOfItem);
      ItemModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: statusOfItem.id }, { $set: { status: statusOfItem.state } }, 
             {new: true})
            .then((updatedItem) => {
                console.log(updatedItem);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                    console.error('Error when updating with new status ' + err);
                });
        }
        
</script>
```

But my issue is, that i get the error message:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: ItemModel is not defined**
at getSelectedValue (SR790123-7:213)
at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (SR790123-7:112)

So I am not able to access the mongoose model I have created and also exported.
And I looked for this issue and found some information that it is not possible to use mongoose when working with browser/client-side JavaScript. I tried to implement browserify but then I am getting the error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/src/queries.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

when adding the path in src () and that file exists and is in the folder.

Thank you in advance and I am grateful for every help I get.

Best regards,
Christian

Comment: So you have client side and server side code. You cannot access mongodb directly from your client with onchange event. Inside OnChange event you must do ajax get or post request to your backend (nodejs) action and inside it you will be able to access and update your mongoDB

Comment: Hey! Thank you for that information! It is working now!